# Match IPv6 protocol using nftables

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6, nftables

In nftables I can use follwoing rule to match IPv4 UDP DNS packets.

```
ip protocol udp udp dport 53 accept
```

but IPv6 variant

```
ip6 protocol udp udp dport 53 accept
```

fails and nftables says

```
v0001.nft:39:5-12: Error: syntax error, unexpected protocol
ip6 protocol udp udp dport 53 accept
    ^^^^^^^^
```

According to [examples in documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes) ip6 has no protocol field but how can I match these packets based on protocol using nftables? Why protocol is not present there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR:

- Be sure to use an *inet* family table and not the default *ip* family, as [described in the wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Nftables_families#inet):

  > Both IPv4/IPv6 packets will traverse the same rules. Rules for IPv4
  > packets won't affect IPv6 packets. Rules for both L3 protocol will
  > affect both.
- Don't use duplicate rules. The goal of the *inet* family is to factorize common rules:

  ```
  # nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain udp dport 53 accept
  ```

  will affect both IPv4 and IPv6.
- If you really want to distinguish them, use `meta nfproto XX`, don't use `ipXX protocol YY`:

  ```
  # nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv4 udp dport 53 accept
  # nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv6 udp dport 53 accept
  ```

Also, while OP's example rules don't show this case,

- If you want to match entirely a whole layer 4 protocol without using an associated specific match (`tcp`, `udp`...) likewise, you can do:

  ```
  # nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv4 meta l4proto udp
  # nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv6 meta l4proto udp
  ```

For details, read below.

---

Your question doesn't include an actual important information: the [table](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#TABLES) this rule is added into.

I'll assume you are really using an *inet* family table which handles both IPv4 and IPv6 together.

Not like this:

```
nft add table ip mytable
```

or this (which is the same):

```
nft add table mytable
```

but like this:

```
nft add table inet mytable
```

Every command you write later must include *inet* or it will still attempt to add *ip*. Like:

```
nft add chain inet mytable myuserchain
```

Now because the layout of [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header) is a bit different, so are their associated keywords in the rule syntax. The IPv6  [Fixed Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header) doesn't include directly what protocol it is carrying. It includes the next header's protocol in "Next Header" and its associated keyword in *nftables* is `nexthdr`. But the next header is actually not always the one with the data payload, it could be any other [Extension Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers), and you could have an IPv6 UDP packet where the IPv6's Fixed Header's next header value is not UDP.

So while IPv4 would work correctly like this:

```
nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain ip protocol udp udp dport 53 accept
```

its direct IPv6 equivalent would *appear* to work, but not always with:

```
nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain ip6 nexthdr udp udp dport 53 accept
```

because it wouldn't match packets which include [Extension Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers). Of course this would be a nightmare for the end user of *nftables* to have to handle this considering also there can be multiple extension headers.

As the system already knows all this, the information you actually care about: IPv4 vs IPv6  (not the fact that it's IPv4 UDP vs IPv6 UDP, which is a syntax workaround to get `ip` and `ip6` accepted: UDP is handled separately in the next (final) match keyword `udp`), is available as [*meta information*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Meta) rather than packet's content information:

> ```
> nfproto <protocol>        
>
> meta nfproto ipv4
> meta nfproto != ipv6
> meta nfproto { ipv4, ipv6 }
> ```

You were just trying to solve a syntax workaround when it wasn't the one to be used (it would check twice for UDP when checking once is enough). The correct syntax for ***both*** cases should be:

```
nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv4 udp dport 53 accept
nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv6 udp dport 53 accept
```

The same exists for the Layer 4 protocol in case there's no specific match used later:

> ```
> l4proto <protocol>        
>
> meta l4proto 22
> meta l4proto != 233
> meta l4proto 33-45
> meta l4proto { 33, 55, 67, 88 }
> meta l4proto { 33-55 }
> ```

here 22 doesn't mean *port 22*, it means *protocol 22*, aka [*xns-idp*](https://salsa.debian.org/md/netbase/-/blob/v5.6/etc-protocols#L22).

Note that using more specific matches already implictly include those *meta* filters in the resulting bytecode (which can be checked with `nft -a --debug=netlink list ruleset`). They become explictly needed only when there's no need to filter further.

That was about the syntax. Of course the whole goal of the *inet* table is to avoid duplication of rules. So in this case, both should be replaced simply with:

```
nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain udp dport 53 accept
```

which will handle both IPv4 and IPv6: because that's what this table family exists for.

Note: `protocol` is probably best used in the *bridge* family table case.

Comment: Thanks for complex answer. I was using inet table of course. Problem was solved using non-separated ip4 and ip6 rule. Thanks.

Comment: @A.B just to make one thing clear to me does `nft add rule inet mytable myuserchain meta nfproto ipv6 drop` drop all ip6 packets in mytable myuserchain?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux that's correct (nitpicking: `mytable` should always be referenced `inet mytable`, because `mytable` alone means `ip mytable`. Then all this could have been done in `ip6 mytable` if IPv4 isn't needed and then specifying the L3 protocol with  nfproto wouldn't be needed) .