# How do I make nftables log dropped packets?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall

I seem to have made nftables log all incoming traffic that is allowed instead of only denied traffic, and I cannot figure out how else to say "deny and log everything else".

Here is my `/etc/nftables.conf` file:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0;

    # Accept any localhost traffic
    iif lo accept

    # Accept traffic originated from us
    ct state established,related accept

    # Accept neighbour discovery otherwise IPv6 connectivity breaks
    ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert } accept

    # Allow incoming SSH connections
    tcp dport ssh ct state new counter accept

    # Allow mdns from the LAN
    ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 udp dport mdns counter accept
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp dport mdns counter accept

    ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 log prefix "Rejected: " flags all reject comment "send rejection to LAN only"
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10 log prefix "Rejected: " flags all reject comment "send rejection to LAN only"

    # Log and drop any other traffic
    # THIS IS THE BROKEN PART
    log prefix "Dropped:  " flags all drop
  }
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0;
  }
  chain output {
    type filter hook output priority 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to this question, but you should almost *NEVER* use `ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6`. I'm explaining why and what to use in an answer of mine there: https://superuser.com/questions/1560376/match-ipv6-protocol-using-nftables/1560407#1560407. Use `nfproto ipv6 icmpv6` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by jumping to a separate chain for LAN-only rules, so that the `input` chain has only one log line.  I am not sure why just adding `policy drop` to the `input` chain as suggested by @0xC0000022L was not sufficient.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft --file

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0
    policy drop
    # Normal "prelude" things you always want.
    ct state vmap {
      new: continue,
      established: accept,
      related: accept,
      invalid: drop
    }
    ct status dnat  accept
    iiftype loopback  accept
    icmp type echo-request  accept
    icmpv6 type {
      echo-request,
      nd-neighbor-solicit,
      nd-router-advert,
      nd-neighbor-advert
    } accept

    tcp dport ssh accept comment "Allow incoming SSH connections"

    ip  saddr 192.168.1.0/24  jump lan_only
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10       jump lan_only

    log prefix "Dropped:  " flags all drop comment "non-LAN gets dropped brusquely"
  }

  chain lan_only {
    udp dport mdns counter accept comment "Allow mdns from the LAN"
    log prefix "Rejected: " flags all reject comment "LAN gets rejected politely (others get dropped brusquely)"
  }

  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0
  }
  chain output {
    type filter hook output priority 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you missed the part about the default for chains. From [the manual](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html):

```
{add | create} chain [family] table chain [{ type type hook hook [device device] priority priority ; [policy policy ;] }]
```

That `policy` value mentioned here is described as follows:

> Base chains also allow to set the chain's `policy`, i.e. what happens to
> packets not explicitly accepted or refused in contained rules.
> Supported policy values are `accept` (which is the default) or `drop`.

So I suppose you'll want to switch out these lines:

```
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0;
```

for these:

```
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0;
    policy drop;
```

But make sure you have some way of accessing this machine in case you lock yourself out with your rules. For `iptables` the command to use would be `iptables-apply`, but I am not sure what can be used in its place for `nft`. `iptables-apply` will revert the rules if you are unable to confirm within a given timeout period that you are able to (still) access the host ...

Comment: @A.B oh, oops. Thanks. Should have verified. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, that does look tidier.  I still have the puzzle of how to log denied packets.

Comment: @aidalgol wait, what? Could you please include your updated rule set in your question. This makes little sense, since the last rule is `log` and everything after that should be dropped ... are you perhaps missing something like `ulogd2` or it ends up in the wrong "stream" in syslog?